# maintain stroke while stretching shape, after effects

Tags: expression, scale, after-effects, stroke, proportions

I am trying to stretch and expand this shape without changing the stroke weight but nothing seems to be working. I am working with stroke and using expression to keep the stroke proportionate but so far nothing works.

[this is what my screen looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTey3.jpg)

the expression being used: value / length(toComp([0,0]), toComp([0.7071,0.7071])) || 0.001;

[this is currently what happened when i tried to stretch/expand it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2rBE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

place the shape in a separate group with no fill or stroke. and place the stroke under the group outside. use group transform instead of transforming the layer itself. In other words - transform shapes BEFORE they get any stroke.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).